# ALTER datatype from identity to identity(1,1,1) in vertica

Tags: identity, vertica

we have created vertica tables with ID column having datatype Identity.

The issue is everytime a session is closed or table truncated the ID value jumps to 250000, 500000 so on (cache in vertica defaults to 250000). I understand that if we change the cache to 1, this wouldnt be an issue.

So my question is how can we alter the column to change datatype from identity to identity(1,1,1) ? Or is creating a new table and loading the data the only option I have?

Is there any way of reseeding the Identity column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the caveats after I tell you how to do this. It's really important. I'll apologize in advance for the lecture.

You can't modify `IDENTITY` or `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns in more recent versions of Vertica... at least not directly. You can however solve your problem by altering the sequence generated under the hood.

To find your sequence:

```
SELECT * FROM SEQUENCES
WHERE identity_table_name = 'mytable';
```

Then you should find the autogenerated sequence that corresponds to your identity field (the name may not match if you renamed your column, though).

From there you can alter it and change the cache value.

```
ALTER SEQUENCE mytable_id_seq CACHE 1000;
```

You can also restart the values (like after a truncate).

```
ALTER SEQUENCE mytable_id_seq RESTART WITH 1;
```

**You MUST restart any sessions that have used these sequences for the changes to take effect.** Once a cache is pulled, that cache remains a part of the session.

That said, I feel it is really important to mention something about sequences in Vertica. Sequence cache is really important. Every uncached pull from a sequence is a global catalog lock. This will block certain very important operations from occurring on your cluster if done too often.

As an example, let's say you set your cache to 1 then do an insert/select on a bunch of times.  You just locked your global catalog repeatedly.  In isolation, you may not even notice this however on a busy cluster with a lot of work, you most definitely will.

Another example is poor session handling. Let's say I do something crazy like log in, insert a row and log out (nevermind the fact that single row inserts are generally bad for Vertica). It won't matter how much cache you have, you'll still pay that catalog lock repeatedly.

So be very aware of how you plan to use sequences if you use them in Vertica. Another alternative to this might be to use a UUID (not available in Vertica), use `HASH()`, use a natural key to access your data, or generate them before the data gets to Vertica.

Unless you genuinely insert a single row only every so often, don't do this.

Another important thing to mention is that you should really not use sequences as a form of ordering.  This is more of a best practices thing and really true for any database. First off, if you do loads in parallel, it will not really be representative since cache blocks are used (and with no cache, you can forget about any kind of performance for the reasons I mentioned except exacerbated greatly by doing parallel sequence pulls). Secondly, that's what timestamps are for. You can even default this.

A corollary to this is, always expect gaps when using sequences. There are too many situations that cause sequence gaps. This is also true of any database pretty much.  I could be wrong, but I don't believe any database rolls back sequence pulls on a transaction rollback.

Comment: So there is no direct way to Reseed/Reset the IDENTITY columns in Vertica? Even  with SEQUENCES, 'RESTART WITH 1' works only if i limit the cache of the said sequence to 1.

Comment: You can do restart with, sure. Same process above should work. I don't really follow the only working if you set the cache to 1 though. It'll reset it to whatever you tell it to, but the cache value will always  pull that many sequence numbers on every pull on every session.

Comment: I might have focused too much on your cache to 1 part. If all you are looking for is to reset it on a truncate, by all means... restart with 1. But the cache will still create large gaps, and for all the reasons noted above, I would not set cache to 1.

Comment: And I'm not sure, now that I see your comment again, maybe I wasn't clear. Identity creates a sequence. I'm telling you that you can modify the identity behind the scenes by first finding the sequence, then altering it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes i understood the part of behind the scenes sequences for IDENTITY. Thanks for your time and help :)

Comment: NP- Don't forget that any sessions that used the sequence have to be closed in order for your changes to take effect.  Best of luck!